# Why my parameters don't pop up in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new here. I tried to write a function in VS code, but when I start to write the parameters name in the function block, they don't pop up. Also like you can see in the print screnn, they also shown in white.

Someone know what is the reason?

btw, also I have some error, but I don't know what the VS code wants.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can't define functions INSIDE other functions, look at your **PROBELMS** panel

Comment: Thanks. So in C I must to dedine the function outside the main? I lean a little bit Python, but in Python there is no main function, so I guess I need to do some adjustments (I didn't see in 2 sources that I learn from them that I must to difine it outside). How can I put like to your comment. I still tries to find my hands in this site.

Comment: where have you found a comment that C supports local functions? Every programming language has different syntax.

Comment: I didn't found comment that C support local functions. Also I didn't found any limitaion that wrote to do this.